# ORACLE SQL Select timestamps column from table. Producing more results than intended

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

Hello currently I have a working script below. I am using Oracle 10

```
SELECT z.no as "ID_One",
  MAX(r.value) as "Max", 
  round(MAX(r.value)/80000,2) as "ROUND" 
FROM Table1 r, Table2 z 
WHERE r.timestamp > ((SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60) - 80000 
  AND r.va=21 
  AND r.nor IN ('7','98','3','3') 
  AND r.nor = z.re 
GROUP BY r.nor, r.varr, z.no;
```

It produces a table like this

```
ID_ONE MAX ROUND
105      500 232   
106      232 32  
333      23  .21
444      34  .321
```

I want to select a row call timestamp from table r. However when I add " r.timestamp " in to my query it produces 500 rows of data instead of 4. It looks like it is producing the the highest number for each timestamp instead. How would I produce a table that looks like this ? fyi timestamp column is in unix time. I can do the conversion myself. I just need to know how to get out these rows.

```
ID_ONE MAX ROUND   TIMESTAMP
105      500 232     DEC 21,2021 10:00
106      232 32      DEC 21,2021 23:12 
333      23  .21     DEC 31,2021 2:12
444      34  .321    DEC 31,2021 23:12
```

When I add the column time stamp it does not create what is above. What I am getting instead is something like that looks like this the other two ids are below in this 500 long row of data. I only wanted the 4 that is the highest value (MAX) from this set of time. ID_ONE is my id for a stock of inventory for a warehouse.

```
ID_ONE             ROUND                 TIMESTAMP                  MAX

106                                                              338
                   .06     1406694567

106                                                              355
                   .06     1406696037

106                                                              246
                   .04     1406696337


106                                                              363
                   .06     1406700687

106                                                              330
                   .06     1406700987

106                                                              512
                   .09     1406701347


106                                                              459
                   .08     1406704047

106                                                              427
                   .07     1406711038

106                                                              596
                    .1     1406713111
106                                                              401
                   .07     1406715872
106                                                              682
                   .11     1406726192
106                                                             2776
                   .46     1406726492
105                                                            414
                   .07     1406728863

105                                                              380
                   .06     1406734055

105                                                              378
                   .06     1406734655

105                                                              722
                   .12     1406735555

105                                                              144
                   .02     1406665697

105                                                               5
```

Comment: Your query cannot possibly run because it's missing the group by section. What do you mean by "row call timestamp"? How is it computed?

Comment: @HAL9000 The `group by` is there, it was just not on a separate line. I've edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my answer kindly try the below

```
SELECT z.no as "ID_One",
max(r.value) as "Max", 
round(MAX(r.value)/80000,2)      as "ROUND",r.Timestamp
FROM Table1 r, Table2 z 
where r.timestamp > ((SYSDATE - TO_DATE   ('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM
-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60) - 80000 
   and r.va=21 
   AND r.nor IN ('7','98','3','3') 
   AND r.value=(select max(r1.value) from Table1 r1 where r1.va=r.va and r1.nor=r.nor)
   AND r.nor = z.re group by r.nor, r.varr, z.no;
```

Comment: Wow it's working now. I guess I might had made a typo. How would I convert my timestamp which are numbers like 1406701347 to real time ? I try to use ---- max (TO_CHAR(DATE '1970-01-01' + ( max(r.timestamp) / (24 * 60 * 60)),
    'MON DD,YYYY HH24:MI')) AS timestamp_date--- to do this but it returns me to the same bug I was having before where i get 9000+ rows but it does translate the unix time in to real time

Comment: I correct myself the script above is not working. max(r.timestamp) just grabs the highest timestamp in my data not the timestamp matching the data. This is not what I wanted. I want the timestamp that is in the database that correlates to the information.

Comment: I wanted the MAX value and the timestamp that relates to that.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an ideal use case for analytic functions:

```
SELECT 
  v1.*,
  round(v1.value/80000,2) as rounded_max_value 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    z.no as id_one,
    r.value,
    row_number() over (partition by r.nor, r.varr, z.no order by r.value desc) as rn,
    r.timestamp
FROM Table1 r, Table2 z 
WHERE r.timestamp > 
     ((SYSDATE - TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 60 * 60) - 80000 
  AND r.va=21 
  AND r.nor IN ('7','98','3','3') 
  AND r.nor = z.re 
) v1
where v1.rn = 1
```

This query

- uses `row_number over (partition by .. order by )` to get an ordering of the rows within a group
- uses `rn = 1` in the outer query to get only the row having the maximum value

Some additional recommendations:

- if your `r.nor` column is numeric, then don't use string literals; use `IN (7,98,3,3)` instead (BTW: why do you have `3` twice in your IN list?
- don't use `"` for column aliases unless absolutely necessary (since it makes them case-sensitive) ; they are a PITA
- don't put your JOIN conditions into the `WHERE` clause; it makes your query harder to read. Use ANSI style joins instead.